# Sync + AFNetworking + applicationWillResignActive

Tags: delegates, synchronization, afnetworking

In my iPad app, I use a ViewController called CloudViewController and a "sync engine" class called SyncServicesController (singleton). The 2 communicates with the delegate methods defined in SyncServicesController.

All my sync works properly and communicates what happens to CloudViewController (login, pull, push, error...etc).

The problem happens when a user leaves the apps (applicationWillResignActive).

In AppDelegate, my code is:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication*)application
{
  UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundIdentifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^(void) { 
    [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundIdentifier];  
    [[SyncServicesController sharedServices] cancelAllRequests]; 
  }]; 

}
```

And cancelAllrequests in SyncServicesController:

```
- (void)cancelAllRequests
{
  NSLog(@"CancelAllRequests");

  [[HTTPClient sharedClient] cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"webapp/services/pull"];
  [[HTTPClient sharedClient] cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"webapp/services/pull_items"];
  [[HTTPClient sharedClient] cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"webapp/services/pull_image"];
  [[HTTPClient sharedClient] cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"webapp/services/push_item"];  
  [[[HTTPClient sharedClient] operationQueue] cancelAllOperations];

}
```

When the user leaves the app, the sync continue execution of AFNetworking blocks called in SyncServicesController. OK.
But when user come back in app, it's crashing.

Here for example, in SyncServicesController, where the delegate is called (EXEC_BAD_ACCESS) :

```
  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) 
  {
    [self pullUpdateClientItemsWithServerItems:[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"items"]];
    [delegate syncServicesController:self notifyJob:_T(UPDATING_CLIENT_DATA)];
  } 
  failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
  {
  }];
```

It's like the CloudViewController was killed when entering in background...
What is the best way to manage the delegate of SyncServicesController when applicationWillResignActive is called ?

Comment: Actually, I have this warning in applicationWillResignActive: "variable backgroundTaskIdentifier is uninitialized when captured by block"

Comment: Can you post the backtrace of the segfault? I think there's a good chance this has to do with `backgroundTaskIdentifier` not being correctly used.

Comment: Also, `[[[HTTPClient sharedClient] operationQueue] cancelAllOperations];` is enough; all of the stuff above that is redundant.

Comment: One last thing: AFNetworking 1.0RC1 added a property attribute that allows individual operations to be continued in the background, without messing with app delegates or anything yourself.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I will try 1.0RC1.